# 3D level editor

Tags: gratis, cross-platform, modeling

I'm looking for fully featured free 3D level editor for my game.

- It should output SCM friendly files (not the meshes and dds of course, just the transforms and such) that let me render it like I want (JSON for instance)
- It should be open source or free.
- Cross-platform is a must, Windows or Linux support a requirement.

Or, if such thing doesn't exist, some kind of library or tool to help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can use COLLADA format. It is just a 3d object in XML. Editor such as Blender can export into this format and a lot of 3d engine can read it. Hope it helps